# Setting Max-Height to A Dynamic Table Is Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that is generated dynamically using javascript and has rows appended to it using jQuery based on the contents of an array.

My problem is that I want to assign the table a maximum height using the css `max-height` property so that after a certain height is reached, the table can be scrolled.

This is needed since the table might contain a large number of rows and it would then become too large.

I assigned the table a `display: block` and a css `max-height` property of `200px` but the property seems to be ignored. The table's height still extends beyond the maximum height set. Is there something I am missing?

Here is a stripped down version of my code that shows what I am want to do. I tried placing the table in a div like kuba suggested but it still doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#mylink").click(function()         
                     {
    var jsvCustomIcons = [ "images/img1.png","images/img2.png","images/img3.png","images/img4.png","images/img5.png","images/img6.png" ];                       

    var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    $(mydiv).attr("id","mydiv");

    var iconSettingsTable = document.createElement("table");
    $(iconSettingsTable).attr("id","iconSettingsTable");

    var tempTR,tempDescTH,tempDelTH;
    var tempDescTD,tempDelTD,tempImg,tempImg2,tempBold;

    tempTR = document.createElement("tr");
    $(tempTR).addClass("selectorRowHeader");
    tempDescTH = document.createElement("th");
    $(tempDescTH).addClass("selectorColHeader");
    $(tempDescTH).html("Description");
    tempDelTH = document.createElement("th");
    $(tempDelTH).addClass("selectorColHeader");
    $(tempDelTH).html("Delete");
    $(tempTR).append(tempDescTH);
    $(tempTR).append(tempDelTH);
    $(tempTR).css("background-color","#d3d3d3");
    $(iconSettingsTable).append(tempTR);

    for(i=0;i<jsvCustomIcons.length;i++)
    {
      tempTR = document.createElement("tr");
      $(tempTR).addClass("selectorRowData");
      tempDescTD = document.createElement("td");
      $(tempDescTD).addClass("selectorColData");
      tempBold = document.createElement("b");
      $(tempBold).html(jsvCustomIcons[i]);
      $(tempBold).addClass("iconDescriptionTexts");
      tempImg2 = document.createElement("img");
      $(tempImg2).attr(jsvCustomIcons[i]);
      $(tempImg2).addClass("iconDescriptionImages");
      $(tempDescTD).append(tempBold);
      $(tempDescTD).append(tempImg2);

      tempDelTD = document.createElement("td");
      $(tempDelTD).addClass("selectorColData");
      tempImg = document.createElement("img");
      $(tempImg).attr("id","delImage" + i);
      $(tempImg).attr("src","images/delete.png");
      $(tempImg).css("margin-top","5px");

      $(tempImg).click(function()
                       {
        // Code to handle clicks
      });

      $(tempDelTD).append(tempImg);
      $(tempTR).append(tempDescTD);
      $(tempTR).append(tempDelTD);
      $(iconSettingsTable).append(tempTR);
    }
    $(iconSettingsTable).css({"position":"absolute","top":$("#iconSettingsSpan").position().top + 20,"left":0});
    $(mydiv).append(iconSettingsTable);
    $("body").append(mydiv);
  });
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#iconSettingsTable {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.selectorColData {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='iconSettingsSpan'>
  <a class='link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='mylink' >Click for Icon Table</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you also a share the related part of code?

Comment: Please provide some jsfiddle with your code. One thing you can do for sure is to wrap your table in a div, and for this div you can set max-height + overflow properties not for table.

Comment: Ok I'll share a jsfiddle in a moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Line 62 of the JavaScript change to position:auto https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/dmu5wrd0/

```
$(iconSettingsTable).css({"position":"auto","top":$("#iconSettingsSpan").position().top + 20,"left":0});
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. Yes the problem was from setting the position to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the "position: absolute" property of that table

Remove that from jquery code (line no 62 )

or use this

```
#iconSettingsTable
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    position : static !important;
}
```

or use this

```
#mydiv
{
   max-height:100px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   position : relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ajith. It works after setting the position to static. Though I'm not sure why this would happen with position absolute. This is the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e6gayjps/4/

Comment: if you need to use absolute position u need to set it relative to that div by setting #mydiv { position : relative; }

Comment: Yes that would work. And it works if I set the div's position to absolute as well.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, it seems that if I set the div's position to absolute, it works. My problem was that I was setting the table's position to absolute. Here is an updated jsfiddle:

```
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/e6gayjps/5/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to note that setting [`max-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights) directly to the table is unreliable:

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

Therefore, as you already did, the solution is setting it to a non-tabular parent.

But there is a problem with your approach: your table has `position: absolute`, so it's taken out of the flow, and thus the height of the parent `div` is `0`. And even if you set an explicit height to it, [`overflow: scroll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) won't work, because

> ['overflow'] affects the clipping of all of the element's content
>   except any descendant elements (and their respective content and
>   descendants) whose containing block is the viewport or an ancestor of
>   the element.

In your case, since the table is positioned its [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#containing-block-details) isn't the parent `div`:

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is
>   established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute',
>   'relative' or 'fixed'

Therefore, to make it work you need to remove table's `position: absolute`, or set a `position` different than `static` to the parent `div`.